# Texture transparency with P3D

Tags: opengl, processing, blending

I’m currently coding a “Doom” clone, using P3D. I’m not using any external library.
I’m having a weird artifact that happens when I’m using a masked texture. I’ve tried several methods to fix it, but to no avail :(. DISABLE_DEPTH_MASK suppresses the artifact, but then my sprite get sorted all wrong.

If anyone can point me in the right direction, I would really appreciate it! I’m so close to having a functional engine!
(disregard the “doom” face and soldier sprites, of course, they are just temporary assets I’m using…)

artifact1
[image: artifact1]
As you can see, eventhough the mask is working (see the feet of the soldier) it’s leaving a huge black (background color) artifact behind.

artifact2
[image: artifact2]
When walking behind the quad, the artifact isn't too bad but still present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use/enable [**Blending**](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Blending). 
This technique is used if you want ot render a sprite which is not completely opaque , but has partly or completely transparent areas

The soldier has be rendered at the end, after the environment of the scene is finished. The depth test has to be enabled.

Enable blending before you render soldier sprite (texture) with the alpha channel.

```
gl.glEnable(GL.GL_BLEND);
gl.glBlendFunc(GL.GL_SRC_ALPHA,GL.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

And disable blending after:

```
gl.glDisable(GL.GL_BLEND);
```

Note, the "black" background of the soldier sprite has to have an alpha channel of 0.0 (completely transparent) and the alpha channel of the soldier itself has to be 1.0 (completely opaque). In common PNG images fulfill this.

Explanation:

At the point when the soldier is rendered, then the background has already been drawn and the background color (color of the environment) has been stored in the framebuffer.
The blending function is:

```
dest.rgba = dest.rgba * (1 - src.a) + src.rgba * src.a
```

where `dest.rgba` is the color in the framebuffer and `src.rgba` is the color of the sprite.

If the alpha channel of the sprite is 1.0 (`src.a = 1.0`; opaque), then

```
dest.rgba = dest.rgba * (1.0 - 1.0) + src.rgba * 1.0

dest.rgba = src.rgba
```

If the alpha channel of the sprite is 0.0 (`src.a = 0.0`; transparent), then

```
dest.rgba = dest.rgba * (1.0 - 0.0) + src.rgba * 0.0

dest.rgba = dest.rgba
```

Comment: Thanks for that very precise answer!
I'm going to try to see how I can call these functions within processing. While I know Processing fairly well, using OpenGL within the IDE is something I'm completely new at!
Thanks again!

Comment: I've tried what was posted in the forums, but I'm getting a "null pointer" error... I'm not a "programmer" by StackOverflow standards, so I'm figuring out a lot of this... Processing is very friendly to people like us, but we can reach our limits very fasr :) - Thanks again for your very detailed answer: I will find a way! :)